# How to show text while writing on other one?

Tags: java, android, textview

I built an app which is medical calculator and there is a lot of texts there and every `TextView` express specific value like

> ptn = patient name
>
> wt = weight
>
> hit = hight
>
> ... etc

and may be the user forgot what he have to write in the text while he writing, So I suggest a method to remember him and that by putting extra `TextView`at the bottom of the screen, so when the user doesn't writing the text is empty.. then when he click on "ptn" the text below show "patient name" then when he left the text and click on the next text "wt" the text below erase "patient name" and replace it with "weight".. etc

and suggest for that this code :

```
e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
StringV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StringV);
    ////
    e1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringV.setText("");
        }
    });

 e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            StringV.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            StringV.setText("Patient Name");

        }

    });
```

but when run the app the result was depressed!

when i click on the next text the below one didn't change it change just while i'm writing on the text i want it to change when i click on the next text till finishing the writing and click on the next text ..

**How to do that, please ?**

Answer (score 1):

I think your work can be done with simple :

```
public class YourClass extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{

    EditText name , weight;
    TextView StringV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
        StringV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StringV);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Name:
            StringV.setText("Patient Name");
            break;
        case R.id.Weight:
            StringV.setText("Weight");
            break;
        // write as many cases as you want
        default:
            StringV.setText(" ");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

if it helped don't forget to thanks and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use hacky and non-standard ways of achieving this functionality. Android already provides a solution for this type of problem in its [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), using Floating labels for EditText. You're supposed to use [TextInputLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) which I recently explained in a [blog post](http://blog.antrromet.com/2015/07/floating-labels-for-edittext-hint.html) of mine.

Comment: did you mean using that : "<string name="name">Patient Name</string>" ??

Comment: What? I didn't get you. Please go through the links i posted in my answer.

Comment: The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Comment: Did you add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` to your build.gradle file? It is explained in the blog post!